# Understanding of Example of Linear Independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Lemma. The two functions $e^{t},e^{2t}$ are linearly independent. To prove this, suppose that there are numbers $a,b$ such that $ae^{t}+be^{2t}=0$ (for all values of $t$). Differentiate this relation. We obtain

$ae^{t}+2be^{2t}=0$

Subtract the first from the second relation. We obtain $be^{2t}=0$, and hence $b=0$. From the first relation, it follows that $ae^{t}=0$, and hence $a=0$. Hence, $e^{t},e^{2t}$ are linearly independent.

My question that why did we differentiate of this equation?

Comment: You don't have to differentiate it. It was just helpful to do so because it gives you more data to work with. An alternative would be to set $t=0$ and $t=1$, yielding respectively $a+b=0$ and $a+be=0$ and consequently $a=b=0$.

Comment: Another way: multiply by $e^{-2t}$ and let $t\to\infty$. This will work with any sum $a_1e^{k_1t}+\dots+a_ne^{k_nt}$ with $k_1<\dots<k_n$. First multiply by $e^{-k_nt}$, prove $a_n=0$, then do the same with $k_{n-1}$, etc.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

We differentiate to prove the linear independence of these functions. That is the functions you have provided are $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$. One (relatively simple) way to prove its linear independence is to just differentiate since it results in a simple expression that is equivalent and equally powerful in showing that $a, b$ must both $0$. That is that:
$$\frac{dae^t + be^{2t}}{dt} = \frac{d0}{dt}$$
Of course, there are many other ways to prove its linear independence, this is just one way and probably the most easiest to use. If we continually differentiate, we can show that $a = b = 0$